# Node js 'readline' - Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httprequest, v8

Her's what i am doing in the code

Basically doing web scraping

i am Reading a text file with around 3500 links then i am reading each link , filtering the one i want and doing a request to get the status code, link, and page title (using cheerio).I slowed the process down with async iterator structure for reading line by line as well as using axios and async await. Everything work fine till like the 900th link  i get this Nasty FATAL ERROR ***'FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory'*** 
[image]

I have no idea what's going on here , is this the webserver kicking me out (doesn't look like) or my code is badly written and the v8 engine is not handling it ?(more likely)

Here is my code , if any one want to try running with big amount of links, i used https://hackertarget.com/extract-links/ to get the links then put it in a text file.

```js
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = require('url-parse');
var axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const timeout = require('./timeout')

var main = [];
async function processLineByLine() {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/T440/Documents/crawl/links.txt'),
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    if (line.startsWith('https://www.example.com')) {
      var encodeLink = encodeURI(line);
    
      const response =  await axios.get(encodeLink).catch((err)=>{
        var Status_ErrorsCatchaxios = {
            "status Code": err.response.status ?error.response.status:"No status code available",
            "Page title:": $('title').text()?$('title').text():'No title avaialble',
            "Original Link": encodeLink?encodeLink:"No Original Link Available",
            "errorCode":err
          }
          main.push(Status_ErrorsCatchaxios)
      })
      try {
        const body = response.data;
        if (response.status === 200) {
          // Parse the document body
          var $ = cheerio.load(body);
          var Status_200 = {
            "status Code": response.status,
            "Page title:": $('title').text(),
            "Original Link": encodeLink,
          }
          main.push(Status_200)
        }
  
        if (response.status === 302 || response.status === 404 || response.status === 500) {
          // Parse the document body
          var Status_Errors = {
            "status Code": response.status,
            "Page title:": $('title').text(),
            "Original Link": encodeLink,
          }
          main.push(Status_Errors)
        }
            fs.writeFile("C:/Users/T440/Documents/crawl/output.json", JSON.stringify(main), (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
          });
      } catch (error) {

          var Status_ErrorsCatch = {
          "status Code": response.status ?error.response.status:"No status code available",
          "Page title:": $('title').text()?$('title').text():'No title avaialble',
          "Original Link": encodeLink?encodeLink:"No Original Link Available",
        }
        main.push(Status_ErrorsCatch)
      }      
        
    }
  }
}
processLineByLine()
```

Comment: I have the same problem, can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am having the same problem.  Originally found this reference to the problem: [cheerio+v8 "leaks" memory](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/263).  I think it is a memory leak in Cheerio/V8.  I haven't found the solution to my problem yet, but I have tried the following:

1. Create an Unleak function as found here: [Unleak](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2869)
2. Run node with more memory 'node --max-old-space-size=8192 app.js'
3. Run node with the garbage collector exposed and call it 'node -expose-gc app.js' call Global.gc()

1 and 2 had the most effect.  I am sure it is just my code as this is problem old.

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2022

I had to read a text file that contained over 200 millions domains stored line by line. With this amount of data, you can imagine how Node freaked out as well as my laptop.

SO, I want to provide a solution that does not involve increasing memory size or anything crazy like that. There's a known memory leak issue with cheerio, readline and v8. After reaching a certain limit your Node server will self-destruct and kill all processes. Increasing the size of memory may or may not work. In my case, it did not work. In fact, after increasing memory it was worst and crashed earlier than it did before.

### TLDR;

If you want to read EXTREMELY LARGE files (thousands or millions of lines) ***line by line***, you can do it with library `event-stream`. Everything else failed for me and I tried many different solutions.

```
//event-stream
const es = require('event-stream');//npm i event-stream

//timestamp
const timestamp= Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);
 
//declare array
var domains = [];

//get line count for file
var lineCount = 0;

//stream
var s = fs
.createReadStream('domains.txt')//your extremely large file goes here Jedi you
.pipe(es.split())
.pipe(
es
.mapSync(function(line) {

//count line
lineCount++;
var count = lineCount++;

//domain
var domain = {
id : count,
timestamp : timestamp,
domain : line,
}

//push domains to json array collection
domains.push(domain);

//console.time('line count');
console.log(domain);

})
.on('error', function(err) {
console.log('Error while reading file.', err);
})
.on('end', function() {

//done
console.log('Read entire file.');

//print total lines
console.log(lineCount);
console.timeEnd('line count');

//print json array to do whatever
console.log(domains);
}),
);
```